# Assignability error - cannot use r.x (variable of type int) as Numerator value in return statement

Tags: go

In the below program, composite types(`X` & `map[string]int`) doesn't need explicit conversion, for assignability, because underlying type of composite types(`X` & `map[string]int`) is `map[string]int`, looks fine

```
package main

type X map[string]int

func main() {
    var x X
    var y map[string]int
    x = y
    y = x
}
```

---

In the below code,

```
package main

type RationalNumber struct {
    x int
    y int
}

type Numerator int
type Denominator int

// Constructor
func newRational(n, d int) RationalNumber {
    g := gcd(n, d)
    return RationalNumber{
        x: n / g,
        y: d / g,
    }
}

// Selector
func (r RationalNumber) numer() Numerator {
    return r.x
}

func (r RationalNumber) denom() Denominator {
    return r.y
}

func main() {

}

func gcd(a int, b int) int { // (15, 21) (-15, 21) (15, -21) (-15, -21)

    var f func(int, int) int
    f = func(x int, y int) int {
        if x%y == 0 {
            return y
        }
        return gcd(y, x%y)
    }
    if mod(a) < mod(b) {
        return f(mod(b), mod(a))
    }
    return f(mod(a), mod(b))
}

func mod(x int) int { // helper
    if x < 0 {
        return -x
    }
    return x
}
```

---

underlying type of identifier `Numerator` is `int` and `r.x` is of type `int`, but `return r.x` gives error.

So, why `return r.x` gives error? `cannot use r.x (variable of type int) as Numerator value in return statement`

Answer (score 2):

This is mentioned in the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/basics/13)

> Unlike in C, in Go assignment between items of different type requires
> an explicit conversion.

But why not use `Numerator` and `Denominator` in the definition of `RationalNumber`?

```
type Numerator int

type Denominator int

type RationalNumber struct {
    x Numerator
    y Denominator
}
```

Comment: why not use? Because the representation of data( in `RationalNumber` struct ) can change to `pair [2]int`. `Numerator` type is for usage and exposed to public

Answer (score 1):

> So, why return r.x gives error? cannot use r.x (variable of type int) as Numerator value in return statement

Because while the underlying types are the same, the types are not. Just [convert](https://go.dev/tour/basics/13) to the underlying type when returning:

```
return r.x.(Numerator)
```

Comment: types are not? Query edited